# "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

Tags: asp.net, angular, http, post, asp.net-web-api

i M doing  post request from angular 2 with asp.net webapi 2 
when i m running my app. it giving me above error message
i checked its response in fiddler as

<[image]>

i search on google for the solution and made changes according to suggestion but still i m facing the same error.
**Asp.net web api code is:-**

```
public void postvalidUser(string UserName,string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            var login = uData.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == UserName).ToList();
            if (login != null && login.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var log in login)
                {
                    if (log.UserName == UserName && log.Password == Password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("login ok");

                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("login fail");

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex){

            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

**login.servuce.ts code**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  postvalidUser(UserName: string, Password: string) {
    const users = { UserName: UserName, Password: Password };
    let body = JSON.stringify(users);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers });

    return this._http
      .post("http://localhost:65440/api/User", users, options)
      .map(result => result.json());
  }

  }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _loginservices: LoginService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  OnClick(UserName: string, Password:string) {
    this._loginservices.postvalidUser(UserName, Password)
         .subscribe(users => console.log(users));

  }
```

**login.component.html**

```
  <div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>UserName</td><td><input [(ngModel)]="UserName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input [(ngModel)]="Password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="OnClick(UserName.value,Password.value)">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Please correct me if i have some error in my code

Comment: Your code isn't the error, you have to add the POST method to the list of allowed methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your API. You are missing the `HttpPost` verb and also your method needs a return type instead of `void`. You also need a model to accept your values

```
public class User 
{
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

Then use that model inside the your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult postvalidUser(model User)
{
    //Do whatever needs to be done.
    //if log in is successful then return Ok()        
    return Ok();
    //if log in is NOT successful then return BadRequest()
}
```

Your **service** will look like this

```
postvalidUser(UserName: string, Password: string) {
    let users = { UserName: UserName, Password: Password };

    return this._http
      .post("http://localhost:65440/api/user", users)
}
```

**component**

```
OnClick(UserName: string, Password:string) {
    this._loginservices.postvalidUser(UserName, Password)
         .subscribe(users => console.log(users),
                    error => {
                        //check the error code here, if it 400 then log in information supplied was incorrect 
                    });

}
```

The headers are not needed, nor is the `JSON.Stringify`.

Comment: sir when i m giving [HttpPost, Route("api/User")] as my controller name is UserController . it not showing me any api output when i m running my apis. It giving me error like :- No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:65440/api/User'.

Comment: .still it was giving me same error . i put debugger in my component and service . my username and password is going through component and services but not going in backend api.                                                
 when i was putting UserName.value and Password.value in my html OnClick event. i get undefined username and passeord in debugger checking. while if i remove .value . i giving me username and password in dubugger .  but at the end error is still same

Comment: please help me for some more time

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is or what you're trying to ask?

Comment: i m doing a post request in that i wanted to check my username and password with my database

Comment: I only wanted if my credential is correct  then it should show that on console and if wrong then it show null on console

Comment: @Tej which console? browser or .net console?? debug by putting a break point in your backend service, then you will know whats happening.

Comment: browser console

Comment: Ok, so you need to return BadRequest() or something when the user enters in information that is in correct. Then inside your angular code, you can check the error code and display the information accordingly?

Comment: yes sir. i wanted to check that infront end side and according to that display result

Comment: I updated my answer to include the error part of the subscribe event

Comment: yaa its working. thank you soo much sir for your valuable help ;)

Comment: @Sachin  thank you sir as u suggest i also debug my api's and i modified my api.